# Ubuntu Edge in Japan

Tags: ubuntu-edge

I'm not terribly knowledgeable about cell phones.  The edge looks exciting and I like supporting gadgets that are powered by open source, but I live in Japan.  Could somebody point me to online info that would let me know whether or not I could use this device to make phone calls here in Japan?

Answer (score 4):

"The Ubuntu Edge is an open device, not locked to any particular network. It works in all countries that provide GSM/3G/LTE-based network services", I quote from the project site. From that it is clear you can use it in Japan with any network that provides GSM/LTE services.

For further information, you can visit this [LINK](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge) .

I hope that is what you are asking for.

Thank you.

Comment: Will LTE work, I am not sure. LTE has different bands and different country adapted different LTE band. For example LTE band in india and china are completely different. Also take example of iphone, they made different phones for different band/ country. At this point it is unclear whether LTE will work.

Comment: "It will also support the two LTE standards to provide 4G mobile broadband connectivity around the world (subject to network availability and data fees).", from the project site. That will be subject to the two known standard. In that case it will likely work any bands available at the moment. In other words, dual-LTE is more or less a multi-band LTE network compatible. I would like to say you must know your network LTE band before opting for the device.

Comment: I sent the Ubuntu Edge team this question about whether or not I can use the Edge in Japan.  Would you like to know the answer?  LTE/GSM...

Why is that answer a problem?  Because Japan does not have GSM.  What is more the LTE system uses unique bands that no other countries use!  So their ANSWER IS USELESS... (> <)  Oh well I really want to get this phone, but given that I live in Japan there is no way I am going to sink $700 into something that I don't know for sure I can use.