# Will the Ubuntu Edge work with 800MHz CDMA networks in India

Tags: ubuntu-edge, cdma

I am based in india using Reliance, CDMA

For CDMA in India, the frequencies are: 
824 - 844 MHz for the uplink (handset to base station) 
869 - 889 MHz for the downlink (base station to handset) 
20 MHz band for uplink & downlink.
carrier freq. is 1.25MHz

since i am interested in purchasing the phone, and the phone does not come cheap , can you guys confirm that it will work in india.

Thanks
Nitin

Comment: This is off-topic. See similar closed question here that contains link to details regarding your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/323826/ubuntu-edge-in-japan?rq=1

Comment: This question has a good answer. I think we should let it be. @Braiam why do you think this is a duplicate?

Comment: @Seth huh? The flag was marked as "helpful", please lets discuss this in [chat]

Comment: @nitink Please follow the link of my first comment, if you want support for your region, since it takes the user base to decide the scope of the launching.

Comment: how can my question which enquires about frequency be treated same as to "How to order the Ubuntu Phone?" Its like comparing apples with oranges.

Comment: also ubuntu edge should have been a global phone working in any frequency. you guys would have got much better response.

Answer (score 3):

No. It's a GSM/3G/LTE-based device.

Comment: off late all handsets especially in US like droid razr series from motorola , HTC etc are world phones which work in all regions as cdma or gsm ( one at a time). hope ubuntu edge would have followed that as well :(